# how to set default permissions for local files newly checked out of subversion via eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, permissions

I'm using Eclipse 4.2.0 (Juno) and with Subversive. When I check out a file or revert to most recent from repository, the local file defaults to 600. I would like it to default to 644. I looked in Eclipse->Preferences->Team->SVN and found nothing germane.  My google-fu seems to be off too.

I'd really like to not have to remember to chmod files every time I check them out. I could umask the directory, but I don't want Eclipse's and Subversion's dot files to be affected.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check umask setting in your shell. It should be 0022.

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, I'd prefer not to use umask because it will also affect the dot files (.svn, .profile, etc)